# Java Error by intellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this error by intellij

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000c46be13, pid=864, tid=3364
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
         (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C [ig7icd64.dll+0x8be13]
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with Windows user account control (`UAC`). A colleague had a similar issue and resolved it by disabling the UAC. If this should fix your error, make sure you get yourself informed about the consequences of disabling it.

See this link for a howto that covers Vista, 7, 8 and 10.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-user-account-control-uac-the-easy-way-on-windows-vista/